# Creating Custom List View in a Master Detail Flow depending on Device Size

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

The basic template of Master Detail flow uses a `boolean mTwoPane` value to determine if there are going to be two panes or one. However, it is set AFTER the `ListFragment` is rendered. I want to create one `ListView` for small devices which will display `DetailFragment` in a different activity and a different `ListView` on devices which will render the `DetailFragment` side-by-side to the `ListFragment`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
        // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;
        // rest of code
    }
```

I have tried using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list)` after determining `mTwoPane`, but then `mTwoPane` always stays false. I have also tried using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list)` twice, before and after the if block, but the app crashes.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your layout use a FrameLayout (not a Fragment), only after the if block add a Fragment to the FrameLayout.

Comment: @DavidCorsalini - That worked. Thanks a lot. Although I have one doubt. In two-pane devices the proper ListView was loaded just by the replacement to FrameLayout (without adding Fragment to it in code). Why did that happen?

Comment: I think you have a fragment tag in your xml. I'll post this as an answer, accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout use a `FrameLayout` (not a `Fragment`), only after the `if block` add a `Fragment` to the `FrameLayout`.

Get rid of "`fragment`" tag in the xml to keep full control of `Fragment` management.